# No Connect Server when run indexphp on MAMP

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I have to tell you guys first that I'm a newbie of web development but I just got an assignment to maintain website. I copy all important files on server and set my computer to be a localhost with MAMP. After I try to run page index.php on browser but it show me a result like "NO Connect Server". I dont get it why it show me like that. I has tested my localhost by create test.php to do something for testing like echo and it works fine.

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?
Thanks, 
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like, there is no real way to tell what the real problem is.  The only things I can think of are the usual ones:  the MySQL server isn't actually running, the user name or password is wrong, or the user name isn't actually registered in the system.  Sorry that I can't give more details, but you could find more information if you replace the NO connect Server with mysql_error() like this:

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','passwort') or die(mysql_error());

That will print out the error text when the script dies.  With that information, you can start to decode what is actually going on.